# How can I demo a website via an iPad?

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, airplay

I've developed a proof-of-concept that I'll need to demo on a projector (VGA) and I'd like to use the iPad to demo it. I'd like to mirror the page with as little lag as possible, as the proof uses a lot of CSS transitions - the perception of the app may be degraded if it looks laggy.

I've looked at the VGA accessory, but it looks like that does NOT support Safari mirroring. I've also looked at the new Apple TV, but converting from HDMI to VGA may not be possible. Is there any way to do this, short of using a document camera or something similar?

Comment: Which iPad are you using? Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: @ruddfawcett I have access to all three models and 4.x/5.x.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite difficult to convert VGA to HDMI because HDMI is digital, and VGA is analog.  It can be done, but the solution is often overpriced, and not worth it.  In my opinion, you should buy an HD projector, but if you can't then I would try something like [AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com/) and mirror it to your Mac and then connect your Mac to the projector.  Hope this helps!  In the meantime, I'll look for more solutions.

---

**Update August 5, 2016**:

Apple now sells a [lightening to VGA adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD825AM/A/lightning-to-vga-adapter).

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have a jailbroken iPad, you can use the tweak [DisplayOut](http://rpetri.ch/cydia/displayout/) to mirror the iPad screen on various kinds of displays - that page explains the configurations it supports.